# What's the Disjunctive normal form of a tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

What's the Disjunctive Normal form or a tautology with two variables P & Q

is it P̅Q̅ + P̅Q + PQ̅  + PQ or is that completely wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes; the DNF can be built-up from the truth-table of the formula.

Let the formula $E$ has $p+q$ lines in his truth table with $p$ evaluated to **t** and $q$ to **f**.

The formula is equivalent to a formula $D$ of the form $D_1 \lor \ldots \lor D_p$ where $D_1, \ldots D_p$ correspond to the respective lines with **t**.

Every $D_i$ is the conjunct of the [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic)) : positive, if in that line it has value **t** and negative otherwise.

Thus, a tautology being identically true, we have a disjunct for every line in the table.

Comment: Isn't it always possible to do the following? Let $\mathcal{T}(A₁, \ldots, A_n)$ be a tautology containing $A_₁, \ldots, A_n$ as variables. Then $\bigvee_{i=1}^n (A_i ∨  ¬A_i)$ seems to be a tautology, and aren't all tautologies logically equivalent?

Comment: For that matter, need all the variables be expressed, or is it sufficient to even just write $A₁ ∨  ¬ A₁$?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman - Yes, all tautologies are logically equivalent. Thus, every tautological disjunction will do.